# Collection/anthology book including a comic about a female explorer who discovered a planet filled with a race of primitive, mushroom-headed men

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, comics, anthology-book

[NSFW] So it came to the back of my head of a collection of comics filled with adult themes. can't remember what year it was but I do believe it was around 2007-2012. The book had a pink background with a woman holding pistols and had a skimpy theme, a thong bottom, gold coins for pasties. I do believe she was looking at the viewer and wearing sunglasses. Maybe pointing the guns at you. It was a collection of adult stories and well, never wrote down the title, just a mental image of what the cover looked like.

I also remember one of the comics that had a female explorer who discovered a planet filled with mushroom-head primitive race of men. Just men and you know where it goes when you got a lone female explorer on a world of men.

Yeah, Just need closure as it just lies in the back of my head, popping it's image every few months. Thanks and sorry in advance for the content.

Comment: Sounds like work by Azpiri. Namely his Lorna series. Check these covers out and focus on The Ark: https://shop.heavymetal.com/collections/alfonso-azpiri

Comment: No, not the same author. Just looked up his Lorna series and found the Ark. No match. The aliens don't look the same as described. They had literal mushroom-tipped heads, oversized forearms. Also, it was a collection of stories, not just one. Though if I could find that specific story, I can find the collection. Big If.